# Finding polynomial order of parametric curve with trig functions

Tags: calculus, polynomials, parametric

I was given a parametric curve defined by:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \cos(t) \\  
y(t) &= \cos(2^kt) 
\end{align}
And asked:

> For any natural number *k*, eliminating the parameter gives a polynomial of what order?

When I eliminate the parameter, I end up with something that looks like $$y = \cos(2^k\arccos(x)),$$ which seems correct. But this isn’t a polynomial and doesn’t have an order. Am I making a mistake? Did I misunderstand the question or the definition of a polynomial?

Comment: Expand out a few for small values of $k$ and you should notice the polynomial form. Also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: Some helpful formulas: https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/16/05/02/

Answer (score 2):

A heavy hint:
The comment of @Macavity has it all; let me expand on what they say.

First, look at the simplest case, $k=1$, when the equations are $x=\cos t$,
$y=\cos 2t=\cos^2t-\sin^2t=2\cos^2t-1=2x^2-1$. So there you are for the first case.

And $k=2$ asks about $x=\cos t$, $y=\cos4t=\cos\bigl(2(2t)\bigr)=2\cos^2(2t)-1=2(2\cos^2t-1)^2=8\cos^4t-8\cos^2t+2-1\\=8x^4  -8x^2+1$.

Now you see the inductive process.